# Send object from python to C# using RestAPI

Tags: c#, python, rest

Newbie in this so sorry for the mistakes.
I have a C# app that is running and calling python functions. the functions is being called using POST method. In addition, I would like that this call will reply from python to C# object which include 4 arrays. I successfully did passing a simple string but when I am trying to pass an object, it doesnt work. Here is the code:

**C# caller side**

```
public class RootObject
{

    public Array b1 { get; set; }
    public Array cl { get; set; }
    public Array sc { get; set; }
}
public static List<RootObject> post(string path, int Port)
{
                var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:" + 
                Port.ToString());
                var request = new RestRequest("/postmethod", Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/form-data");
                request.AddFile("file", path);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                var json = response.Content;
                var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

                List<RootObject> r;

                r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
                return r;                   
}
```

**Python side**

```
class myscoresobj:
def __init__(self):
    self.b1
    self.cl
    self.sc

@app.route('/postmethod', methods=['POST'])
def index():

if 'file' not in request.files:
    return "file not found"
file = request.files['file']
contents = file.read()
....
myscoresobj = worker(input_q, output_q) 

return str(myscoresobj )
```

Any way how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012335/json-net-deserializeobject-to-list-of-objects

Comment: first check if the returned content string is indeed the correct json

Comment: Should I build a structured JSON object in Python to be sent? myscoresobj is just a standard class? If I send this object I get
j'son = "<class '__main__.myscoresobj'>"'
'content = "<class '__main__.myscoresobj'>"'